# MS Excel formula works except when I add iferror(), then it produces a runtime error 1004

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, runtime-error

I have a formula in a cell:

```
=IF(INDEX(insurance_column_date,LOOKUP(2,1/(insurance_column_to=B59),ROW(insurance_column_to))-4)>0,INDEX(insurance_column_date,LOOKUP(2,1/(insurance_column_to=B59),ROW(insurance_column_to))-4),"No data")
```

And this works perfectly fine in most instances, but when it can't find a lookup value, there's a division by 0 error in `1/(insurance_column_to=B59)`. In this case, I get #N/A. Fair enough. So I add the iferror function to the cell:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(insurance_column_date,LOOKUP(2,1/(insurance_column_to=B59),ROW(insurance_column_to))-4)>0,INDEX(insurance_column_date,LOOKUP(2,1/(insurance_column_to=B59),ROW(insurance_column_to))-4),"No data"),"No data")
```

And everything is perfect. I get "No data" in the appropriate cells.

However, when I run a (totally unrelated) macro--which is supposed to hide certain rows--I now get a run-time error 1004: "Application-defined or object-defined error" when it hits this line: `pWorksheetName = ActiveWorkbook.Names(pCounter).RefersToRange.Parent.Name`

Even if I return the formula to its non-iferror() syntax, the run-time error still comes up. I've read some causes could be that the formula would result in a string of longer than 911 characters (impossible in this case) or containing too many legend entries (don't know what these are). I've run the macro on two separate computers and gotten the same results.

Does anyone know what the cause of this is or how to fix it?

Comment: Try `IF(ISERROR(1/(insurance_column_to=B59), "No data",IF(INDEX(insurance_column_date,LOOKUP(2,1/(insurance_column_to=B59),ROW(insurance_column_to))-4)>0,INDEX(insurance_column_date,LOOKUP(2,1/(insurance_column_to=B59),ROW(insurance_column_to))-4),"No data"))`

Comment: Looks like you forgot to close your bracket for the `IFERROR()` function.  Add another `)` to the end to do so.  Does that fix it?

Comment: Thanks, guys. I entered the line =IF(ISERROR(1/(insurance_column_to=B59)), "No data",IF(INDEX(insurance_column_date,LOOKUP(2,1/(insurance_c‌​olumn_to=B59),ROW(in‌​surance_column_to))-‌`4`)>0,INDEX(insurance‌​_column_date,LOOKUP(‌​2,1/(insurance_colum‌​n_to=B59),ROW(insura‌​nce_column_to))-4),"‌​No data") and got the message "The formula you typed contains an error." but I can't spot it. Excel highlights the 4 that I highlighted in code markup above, but not the minus sign (it seems to correspond with INDEX(array, **row_num**, [column_num]).

Comment: A quick glance gives rise to this question: Are you asking 1/TRUE or 1/FALSE or 1/number or 1/0? One divided by Zero is error: 1/(insurance_column_to=B59); insurance_column=B59 results in true or false

Comment: =insurance_column_to=B59 gives me #VALUE!. Hrm. insurance_column_to is a range of cells (it's a column of cells in the Insurance tab with the heading To, as in the institution to which we're paying insurance fees). Could that be the problem? I was under the impression the LOOKUP function could check a range of cells, but is this because =[range of cells]=[specific value] resolves as an error, which is why I'm getting messed up? The IF() formula I gave in my initial post works perfectly except when no cell in insurance_column_to contains the value in B59, in which case I get #N/A.

Comment: @SteveG. I didn't get a look at your follow up question. If you were asking me, refer to the person with @ and a person's name will fill in. That way the intended person will get the message.

Comment: @SteveG. Why don't you upload a screenshot of what you go so we can see what you are working with. You are using names? Explicitly write out, insurance_column_to = This. If you use "someName = something", you are asking for equality, it will be true or false. In addition, you are also using a "/" which is a division operation.

Comment: @SteveG. Also, with something this long, use dived and conquer technique. Start with the first question and check for integrity. Then the second and check. And so on. Keep them separate on different cells. Then assemble in the last step and make sure it still works.

Comment: @ejbytes and all, I broke it down into chunks and actually went a different route with the isnumber() function: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B59,insurance_column_to))=TRUE,INDEX(insurance_column_date,LOOKUP(2,1/(insurance_column_to=B59),ROW(insurance_column_to))-4),"No data")` Essentially, instead of evaluating the entire function as a whole, I evaluated if there was a match in the insurance column so that, if not, the divide-by-zero part would never get evaluated anyway. I still have yet to test this with the function giving me the 1004, but it shows promise!

Comment: If B59 is in insurance_column_to, MATCH() returns a position as a number. If not, it returns #N/A. And IF() evaluates if ISNUMBER(MATCH()) returns TRUE (has a number/relative position) or not. If TRUE, I go forward with the INDEX() function (in the if-true argument). If not, in the if-false argument, I put my error statement, "No data." Hope this works with that run-time-error-1004 function, but that's on another computer (I'm away from home right now and just threw some test data together). If it doesn't work, I'll be sure to post those screenshots @ejbytes suggested. Any comments?

Comment: As long as all your logical bases are covered, you'll be okay. Keep your pieces of the puzzle somewhere safe to return back to them. After assembly, just tack on the piece, iferror (myassembly,"") and done.